# While printing a Crystal Report I am not able to preview the report and it's giving error message

Tags: php, crystal-reports

I added a new table on an existing Crystal Report's database. I have written code for that table fields and when I am running my code  it's showing that it has failed to retrieve data.

Here is the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message
> '**Source:** Crystal Reports ActiveX
> Designer
> **Description:** Failed to retrieve data from the
> database.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Perhaps the report needs to be re-synchronised with the table structure.

Open the report in Crystal Designer and do ***Database, Verify Database...***